# I am getting CreateContainerError when trying to deploy Jenkins in Kubernetes using an Image I built in Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I have built a Jenkins docker container using bash script below which runs ok. Then I commited it to an image and uploaded it to Docker registry. Now I am trying to deploy it in kubernetes but the pod is failing and I can´t figure out how to solve it. This is the bash script and below there is the yaml file with the deployment and service definitions.

DOCKER BASH SCRIPT

```html
echo "Jenkins"
echo "###############################################################################################################"

mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/Jenkins
cd /home/ubuntu/Jenkins

cat << EOF > Dockerfile
# Dockerfile

FROM jenkins4eval/jenkins:latest
# copy the list of plugins we want to install
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt

# run the install-plugins script to install the plugins
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
# disable the setup wizard as we will set up jenkins as code :)

ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false

# copy the config-as-code yaml file into the image

COPY jenkins-casc.yaml /usr/local/jenkins-casc.yaml

# tell the jenkins config-as-code plugin where to find the yaml file
ENV CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG /usr/local/jenkins-casc.yaml
EOF

cat << EOF > docker-compose.yml
version: "3.1"
services:

  Jenkins:
    container_name: Jenkins
    image: jenkins-casc:0.1
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./plugins.txt:/usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
      - ./jenkins-casc.yaml:/usr/local/jenkins-casc.yaml
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
      - CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG=/usr/local/jenkins-casc.yaml
EOF

cat << EOF > plugins.txt
configuration-as-code
saml
matrix-auth
cloudbees-folder
build-timeout
timestamper
ws-cleanup
github-api
github
ssh-slaves
warnings-ng
plot
sonar
EOF


# Download yaml file

CASC_CONFIG_FILE=/home/ubuntu/Jenkins/jenkins-casc.yaml
CURL_TOKEN="856d36c380982e13f8d84e1b4dab13009b8ebdd4"
CURL_OWNER="slotone"
CURL_REPO="s1g_install"
CURL_FILEPATH="s1_ami_jenkins_master_config.yaml"
CURL_URL="https://api.github.com/repos/${CURL_OWNER}/${CURL_REPO}/contents/${CURL_FILEPATH}"
/usr/bin/curl --header "Authorization: token ${CURL_TOKEN}" --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw" \
  --location ${CURL_URL} -o ${CASC_CONFIG_FILE}


# Build and run Jenkins server

docker build -t jenkins-casc:0.1 .
```

KUBERNETES JENKINS YAML

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  replicas: 1
  template: # template for the pods
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: tpargmdiaz/jenkins-k8s:1.0

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins

spec:
  # This defines which pods are going to be represented by this Service
  # The service becomes a network endpoint for either other services
  # or maybe external users to connect to (eg browser)
  selector:
    app: jenkins

  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
  type: ClusterIP
```

Comment: hi and welcome to stackoverflow. please add logs of failing container as well as output of kubectl get pods and kubectl get events. without information about failing pods there is no way people will be able to help you....

Comment: also your service clashes with your dockerfile. you are exposing port 80 on your service, but according to your dockerfile your are listening on port 8080